# HttpService Vs Remote Objects

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a flex application and need to show the real time data into the chatrs and datagrids.

Eralier we are used Httpservices to showing the real time data and historical data into charts and datagrids. But now we are going to replace the Httpservices to remote objects.

So which places generally need to change. I have a little bit idea about remote objects.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to replace your `HTTPService` with `RemoteObject`, some questions you need riposte yourself.

1. What framework are you going to implement, if any then check their `RemoteObject` `Invoker` Tag if any.
2. Your resultEvent and FaultEvent will vary according to the framework you are going to apply.

If you are going with Flex default `RemoteObject`

1. Then you need to replace all your `HTTPService` with `RemoteObject` tags.
2. Your backend code also requires some changes with business logic should get into methods with the result of `function` or `method` returning an object.

**Finally a suggestion.**

Instead of going with Remote Objects, why not go with Webservice. You can re use the components somewhere else too.

**Updated links about `Cairngorm`**

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/cairngorm_pt5_03.html

http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2007/2/19/Learning-Cairngorm-Part-3

http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/hello-world-cairngorm-example

http://justjoshn.com/entry/contact-manager-part-2-cairngorm-example

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vinoth, First thing let you know, we are uisng Cairngorm framework with remote objects (earlier it is http services with out any framework).And i am new to cairngorm framwwork, so i got confused to applying remote objects in cairngorm framework. If have any simple explanation about this framework, pls send me a link, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display real time data (or "near real time") you should use some kind of pushing mechanism - take a look on BlazeDS and read about polling and streaming.

If you just need to replace your webservices with remote objects you will need to replace the code dealing with the xml response (extracting data etc) with the code dealing with the objects returned by the remote calls. It is not mandatory to use strongly typed objects, but it will help.